# Unable to send path of the folder within the folder

Tags: php

I am sending path to scan and display files and directories to the php through a form But the realpath() seems to be failing for directories within other directories. It only gives the real path of the folders which are in the same location as of the php itself it fails give the path of folders which are not located in the same location. Please Look at my code and tell me what i am doing wrong. Thank You.

Code -

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dir'])){
$dir= $_POST['dir'];
}
else {
$dir = ".";
}
if($handle=opendir($dir)){
while(false!==($file=readdir($handle))){
    if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
        if(is_dir("$dir/$file")){
            $dirs[]=$file;

        }else{
            $files[]=$file;

        }
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
foreach($dirs as $dir){
$dirpath = realpath($dir);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="dir" value="<?php echo $dirpath; ?>" />
<button type="submit" ><?php echo $dir; ?> Path - <?php echo $dirpath; ?>
</button>
</form><br>
<?php
}
foreach($files as $file){
echo "$file <br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding  `$dirpath = realpath("$path/$dir")`  with this i was able to scan and display any directory. Please suggest any corrections or better way to do this here is the code if anybody needs it -

```
<?php
 $files = array();
 $dirs = array();
if (isset($_POST['dir'])){
$path= $_POST['dir'];
}
else {
$path = ".";
}
if($handle=opendir($path)){
while(false!==($file=readdir($handle))){
    if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
        if(is_dir("$path/$file")){ 
            $dirs[]=$file;

        }else{
            $files[]=$file;

        }
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}

//--- This is the part i was looking for ------------------

foreach($dirs as $dir){
if ($path === "."){
$dirpath = realpath($dir);
}
else {
$dirpath = realpath("$path/$dir"); 
}
//--------------------------------------------------------
?>
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="dir" value="<?php echo $dirpath; ?>" />
 <button type="submit" ><?php echo $dir; ?> Path - <?php echo $dirpath; ?>
 </button>
</form><br>
<?php
}
foreach($files as $file){
echo "$file <br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think your code is working fine, i have tested in my side but one thing which give errors that need to define array and all working fine

```
 $files = array();
  $dirs = array();
```

so your code this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['dir'])) {
    $dir = $_POST['dir'];
} else {
    $dir = ".";
}
$files = array();
$dirs = array();
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) {
                $dirs[] = $file;

            } else {
                $files[] = $file;

            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    $dirpath = realpath($dir);
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="dir" value="<?php echo $dirpath; ?>"/>
        <button type="submit"><?php echo $dir; ?> Path - <?php echo $dirpath; ?>
        </button>
    </form><br>
    <?php
}
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo "$file <br>";
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: $s ='variable';  echo "$s  here is dolor s is variable "; output :  variable here is dolor s is variable  . inside the double quotes we can use variable . it will consider as variable not as string .

Comment: @JYoThI yes you are right but i think this is better to understand

Comment: *"" then this is normal string*   I don't agree with this . that's why i posted my previous comment

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam Thank you for your reply my problem is not this. if you keep browsing through the directories it won't give path to the directory inside other directory. check out this example http://codetest.gq/t1/ go to "folder1" and inside that you can see there is no path for "folder3". that is what i want to know why it is not returning the path to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think your statement syntax is wrong,

```
if(is_dir("$dir/$file")){
```

instead of,

```
if(is_dir($dir."/".$file)){
```